# Creating a string with variables

Tags: c++, string

I want to make an output string for my game. This involes getting an objects ID as well as the energy level. Is there a way to make this into a string

```
string Ouput = objects[x]->getIdentifier() + "Had the greater energy -> object" + objects[i]->getIdentifier() + "was deleted" + endl;
```

Thanks

JG

Edit: The return of getIdentifier() is a char.. Its sequencing, so A,B...Z

Comment: I already have the #include namespace std; and #include <string> at the top. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: `String` and `string` are not the same. There is nothing called `String` in the C++ standard library.

Comment: .. and what is the return type of `getIdentifier()`?

Comment: This is just the formatting of the text field.  Corrected to string.

Comment: @M M The getIdentifer() returns a char

Comment: anyone else wanna point out he said `#include namespace std`?  Idk if that's a typo, but you need `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not `+` the `endl` to a string. If you want a new-line, use `'\n'` instead.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

...

string Ouput = objects[x]->getIdentifier() + .... + "was deleted\n";
                                                                ^^
```

If the return type of `getIdentifier()` is a number, you can use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to convert it.

```
string Ouput = to_string(objects[x]->getIdentifier()) + .... + "was deleted\n";
               ^^^^^^^^^
```

If it's a `char` you can use below way:

```
string Ouput = string(1, objects[x]->getIdentifier()) + .... + "was deleted\n";
```

Comment: Thanks :-) when I debug the code, only displays the identifier.

Comment: @KingJohnno Please show us a complete example which illustrates your problem. Be sure to only include the code which recreates the exact issue and no more. Also include example input and output.

Comment: I am getting the error "Cannot add two pointers". - the problem occurs because nothing is output to the screen. (ideally I would like to write this to a file AS a string)

Comment: Read the last guide which is about `char`

Answer (score 1):

If you want an identifier to take in both a string and int pass it in through the function.  You can say void

```
 void  getIdentifier(int id, string description)
{
cout << "What is the id\n";
cin >> id;

cout << "What is the description\n";
cin >> description;
}
```

and then cout both of them.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That won't work. You're passing `description` by value. You need to pass it by reference it you are using it as a return value. `std::string getIdentifier(int i)` might be better.